# I get an uninitialized object from a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, sfml

So i have some troubles getting pointers to work with SFML shapes. I'm not sure if it has something to do with SFML or if I'm doing anything wrong.

In Draw() x(a **ControlWindow**) does not contain valid values, it only shows "**???**" as shown here. However the m_controls(map) contains the correct values for the control object.

I'm quite new to C++ so any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Exception

```
Exception thrown at 0x60B26EE5 (sfml-graphics-2.dll) in OokiiUI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

### Main

```
vector<WindowControl> windowControls;

void Draw ();

int main ()
{
    RectangleShape rect(Vector2f(120,120));
    WindowControl windowControl(nullptr,0);
    Control testControl(&windowControl,1);

    testControl.SetShape(&rect);

    windowControl.AddControl(testControl);
    windowControls.push_back(windowControl);


    return 0;
}
```

### WindowControl

```
class WindowControl : Control
{
public:
    WindowControl ( WindowControl * windowControl, uint64_t uint64 )
        : Control ( windowControl, uint64 )
    {
    }

    void AddControl(Control control)
    {
        m_controls.insert_or_assign(control.GetId(), control);
        m_controlPtrs.push_back(&control);
    }

    vector<Control*>* GetControls()
    {
        return &m_controlPtrs;
    }

private:
    map<uint64_t, Control> m_controls;
    vector<Control*> m_controlPtrs;
};
```

### Draw

```
for (auto x : windowControls)
{
    vector<Control*> *controlPtrs = x.GetControls();
    window->draw(x.GetControl(0)->GetShape());
}
```

Comment: It's likely caused by you copying an object than adding that pointer to a vector. That local object goes out of scope, and you've got a bad pointer: FYI `m_controlPtrs.push_back(&control);` is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem here:

```
void AddControl(Control control)
{
    m_controls.insert_or_assign(control.GetId(), control);
    m_controlPtrs.push_back(&control);
}
```

You add the address of the parameter `control` which is destroyed when the function ends. It looks like you want to add the address of the **copy** that you add to your `map` like this:

```
void AddControl(Control control)
{
    m_controls.insert_or_assign(control.GetId(), control);
    // don't use the parameter here, use the copy you put in the map
    m_controlPtrs.push_back(&m_controls[control.GetId()]); 
}
```

Although that is not ideal because if you send the same `control` twice, it will only appear *once* in the map (updated) but *twice* in the vector of pointers. You can use the returned pait from `insert_or_update` to fix that:

```
void AddControl(Control control)
{
    auto [iter, was_inserted] = m_controls.insert_or_assign(control.GetId(), control);

    // only add to vector if it was not in the map before
    if(was_inserted)
        m_controlPtrs.push_back(&iter->second);
}
```

A side note:

It is more idiomatic to return a reference in this situation rather than a pointer:

```
vector<Control*>& GetControls()
{
    return m_controlPtrs;
}
```

This also breaks *encapsulation* so it may be worth thinking about how you can avoid accessing the internals of your objects so directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are adding the pointer of a local variable into your `m_controlPtrs`:

```
void AddControl(Control control)
{
    m_controlPtrs.push_back(&control);
}
```

Here you take a copy of `Control`, then add the address of that into your `vector`. The moment the function returns, your object goes out of scope and that memory is pointing to uninitialised garbage.

You probably want to update `AddControl` to take a `Control&`.

[@ShadowRanger raises a good point in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697611/i-get-an-uninitialized-object-from-a-pointer/48697660?noredirect=1#comment84394121_48697660): what I've mentioned may fix your issue, perhaps indefinitely, but your design still isn't terrific. Any time you have a `Control` which won't outlive `m_controlPtrs` you're going to encounter this same problem. Your code is small now, but this may eventually turn into a nightmare to fix. It's likely you should instead update `m_controlPtrs` to share (or take) ownership of the `Control` so this problem won't occur.

The easiest way out is to have `m_controlPtrs` declared as a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Control>>`, but it's something *you* should think about.

Comment: Though taking a `Control&` just means the resulting pointer is based on a different object with a lifetime the `vector` has no control over. Unless you know all such `Control`s will always have scope that outlives the `WindowControl` that holds them, you haven't solved the problem, just delayed it. Seems like transferring ownership of the `Control` (so the `vector` stores `Control`, not `Control*`), or using `shared_ptr` (so the creator and `vector<shared_ptr<Control>>` share ownership and the lifetime is as long as either needs it), would be better bets.